# HTTPPost vs HttpUrlConnection POST on Android

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

I am trying to move away from Apache HTTP to HttpUrlConnection in my Android app. I am stuck and I tried looking everywhere but I cannot get through it. Here is what I am trying.

Below is my HTTP code:

```
HttpParams timeoutParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(timeoutParams, 60000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(timeoutParams, 60000);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(timeoutParams);
Cookie podCookie = getPodCookie();
    if (podCookie != null) {
        httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(podCookie);
    }
HttpPost postMethod = null;
postMethod.addHeader("Authorization", "<auth-header>");
try {
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    String queryString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
    String modUrl = url + "?" + queryString;
    postMethod = new HttpPost(modUrl);

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(<String JSON to send>, HTTP.UTF_8);
postMethod.setEntity(entity);
postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse reply = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
```

This is the HttpUrlConnection equivalent of the above code:

```
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry: parameters.entrySet()) {
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
     }

String queryString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
String modUrl = baseUrl + "?" + queryString;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    URL url1 = new URL(modUrl);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(new URI(url), podCookie);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", <auth-header>);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(<String JSON to send>);
    writer.flush()
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    String responseString = WebService.convertInputStreamToString(is);
```

When I try the above, I get a `401 Unauthorized error`. I am using `Charles` and the headers are the same.

When I try to add the query params in the `BufferedWriter` instead of the URL I change the url to the base url, like this:

```
URL url1 = new URL(baseUrl);
```

and add the following line to writer, like this:

```
writer.write(modUrl)
```

When I do this, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

In both the cases, I am getting an `IOException` which is a `FileNotFoundException` on the `InputStream` line.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should dump the headers from the successful httpclient call so you know exactly what headers are being sent with OK request.

Its not clear how you are setting "Authorization" header

Its not clear what Json value is being set into the 'StringEntity'.

you should know exactly what is being sent in a good call ( httpClient call or Curl CLI call ) before you try to use the HttpUrlConnection. Then set the same headers over there, write the same JSON to the Connections' outputStream and you should get the same result.

Curl expression for your two headers and with your JSON Entity in the curl.-d switches value....

```
curl -v -X POST \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: aValueforAuth" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott",...}' \
  http://domain/path?parm1=$urlEncodedVal-1&parm2=$urlEncodedVal-2
```